# Python: R equivalent code for multiple values assignment of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have trying to change the values of a entire data.frame row based on lists.
What I have is this:

```
ph[count][pos] = valList
```

ph: data.frame
count: value (defined by me)
pos: list of values
valList: list of values

I need to change the values of entire row count, for column values pos with values from valList.
The code I posted above does not work..

Help please :)

Many thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without a sample frame with expected output but are you looking for `iloc`: `df.iloc[count, pos] = val_list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positional (integer) indexing of pandas dataframes is done with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[count, pos] = val_list
```

It can take lists or single scalars as row and column indices; it also supports setting.